# SSIS Debugger wont show Progress

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

Just wondering if anybody has faced this issue.It does not seem to be package specific and is sporadic. I simply start my SSIS debugger in Visual Studio. The debugger loads and does nothing, I know the package is running  because I can see the DTSDebugger in the Task Manager and if I let it run long enough it completes. But I don't get the tick marks or the record counts etc. I have to close my Visual Studio and open it again and it works fine.
Please feel free to comment if any information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that I did not have to exit Visual studio as a whole. If I close my package in Visual studio and open it again, it debugs just fine. Guess it might be a bug or something where it does not reload the execution results in some cases. At least this is a better work around instead of having to close and reopen Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 7 years after, this still happens. What works for me is to delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild the solution. After that the breakpoints and the progress icons are back

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried the close project re-open project thing. Strangely, I was able to see progress on some dtsx files but not others.
Tried a re-build and looked at the rebuild results. I noticed that there was a lack of access to one of my dataconnection managers. It was unused, so I removed it from the project. Another error showed the same lack of file access for the dtsx file that wasn't showing progress. I went to the file, added [everyone] to the security with full access. That FIXED it!!
I don't really care about the security implications of opening the file/folder to everyone. I'm so sick of wrestling with SSIS. Anything that can get me there is a win in my book.