# SSIS Package progress not displayed when debugging

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am working in a team with a few developers on an SSIS project, using git (over GitHub) as our source repository. From time to time something happens to some of the packages and they stop showing progress in Visual Studio when debugging the package. The package is clearly running as information is printed in the Debug window, but the view stays on the design view.

This is a similar question to: [SSIS Debugger wont show Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041997/ssis-debugger-wont-show-progress) however closing down Visual Studio doesn't help, and in fact the problem can be recreated on multiple PCs.

The only solution we have come up with is to recreate the package and copy all the artefacts across and recreate the connections, but that is really not optimal.

Comment: Have you tried switch to/from 64-bit debugging?

Comment: To restate: you have an SSIS package, with I assume a Data Flow task. You begin debugging it, but the DFT never displays the innards so you think it's hung? Are there Lookups inside your data flows? If you look at your source, reference and target systems, do you see database activity corresponding to your ETL? Does it show as blocked?